# Position and type of linux partition in dual boot with windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, partition-recovery, dualboot

I have a mbr partition style and use BIOS system. I shrank volume C:\ to make a new partition for linux. Linux partitions are detected as primary partition by windows and they're on the left side of windows's recover partition. Is it fine? Both windows and linux work without any problem?
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxo46.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's fine. MBR is the old style of disk partitioning, it uses the first sector 512 bytes that will hold the partition table. MBR allows for four partitions, but one of them can be extended and hold many more. Windows only boots from partitions marked as primary and I believe it picks the one marked active.

When the computer starts and the boot-sector is read you will get a boot menu, the windows boot management can be changed with bcdedit, the linux boot manager is usually grub2.

Windows can boot linux, although I find that a bit fiddly to setup and Linux Grub can boot Windows. The easiest is to install Linux after Windows and at the end of the installer GRUB will create the bootmenu.

Windows assigns the drive letter by default C:\ but you can assign any letter. Linux uses de /dev/sda1 notation where A is the disk and 1 the partition number. the command blkid will give you an overview. Linux can read and write to the NTFS partition from Windows. The other-way around is more tricky, windows doesn't read ext4 by default and you need applications for that.

The modern way of booting is through UEFI instead of BIOS and GPT instead of MBR, but beware that secure boot is preferred for Windows, most motherboards come with Microsoft keys preinstalled. Secure boot will not always work for linux, so if you have boot issues, turn secure boot off.